# Flyway migrations supporting multiple storage engines

Tags: mysql, oracle, flyway

I'm writing a set of migration files for a generic SQL database using [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/).  The project needs to support Oracle, MySQL, and PostgreSQL, which means my migration files need to be flexible enough to run regardless of which supported database type is being used.

This is a problem in some cases.  For example, if I wanted a migration file to rename a column, the syntax is different between MySQL and Oracle

**MYSQL**

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" CHANGE "old_column_name" "new_column_name" DATATYPE;
```

**ORACLE**

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" RENAME COLUMN "old_column_name" TO "new_column_name";
```

It appears that Flyway has the ability to define query blocks that are only run for [Database-specific SQL syntax extensions](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql.html#syntax) but I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly that is written based on the documentation as it stands.

How do I write a flyway migration file where only a portion is run for a particular storage engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: use placeholders for minor differences or the [solution described in the FAQ](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#db-specific-sql)

Comment: Ah nice -- if it's convenient to provide an example of a placeholder that would help future askers.  Many thanks for the time!